# How to tell what is passed when no value exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

For this code, how do you know that null is returned if there is no value in the querystring?

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
string strValue = context.Request[name];
```

I'm asking because I never know what's being returned in many cases in the .NET framework when you don't get the value expected when it does not exist.

so if `context.Request[name];` is called and the name doesn't exist in the querystring, how do you know it returns null or an empty string so that I can properly handle the case where it does not exist?

Answer (score 8):

Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to check for a Null or Empty string.:

```
string strValue = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request[name]) ?? 
    context.Request[name] : "Some Default Value";
```

Or if you don't have a default value you'd like to set, you can do the check later:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
{
    // It's Null Or Empty
}
else
{
    // It's Not
}
```

### *Update*

Just saw the comment. If you're trying to figure out if referencing a key that doesn't exist in the Params collection (which is what you're using via shorthand), then check the MSDN documentation.

In this case, Params is a `System.Collections.Specialized.NavmeValueCollection`. The documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx). According to the documentation, a `null` value is indeed returned when a key is not found in the collection.

Therefore you don't have to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`. You could just:

```
string strValue = context.Request[name] ?? "Some Default Value";
```

If you want to set a default, or check for `null` otherwise.

Comment: It should be '?' not '??'. Unless you meant to use the null coalesce operator, in which case it would be - string strValue = Request["test"] ??  "Some Default Value";

Comment: I know how to check it.  I'm asking how do you know what will be returned reguardless that I can cover my ass with IsNullOrEmpty.  Why use that if I can simply check for null on objects or members that will only pass null back if it fails

Answer (score 1):

As @Justin Niessner says, you can check the `context.Request[name]` for null as you read it. This is perfectly efficient and reasonable.

If you feel uncomfortable working with nulls, you can examine the collection into which name is the index.

In your example, `context.Request[name]` is shorthand for `context.Request.Params[name]`. Params is a NameValueCollection, which in turn has a property AllKeys. Assuming we're using .NET 3.5 you can then use .Contains() like so:

```
if (context.Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains(name))
{
   // do something
}
```

Also, you specifically mention you're interested in the query string. context.Request[] returns not just the query string, but also Cookies, Form and ServerVariables. For the query string, use

```
if (context.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains(name))
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: It's not that I feel uncomfortable with nulls.  I just can never distinguish if I should be checking for null or some other default returned value when a member doesn't deliver what is expected.

Comment: I'm specifically asking how do I know whether a member will return a null, empty string, or other when it fails to do its job basically.

Comment: I appreciate the `.AllKeys.Contains(name)` part.  I'm surprised nobody else suggested that.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is 'how do I know what the behaviour of this object is?' - in which case I don't know of a better answer than 'check the documentation' - in this case, `HttpContext.Request` is documented as being of type `HttpRequest`, which in turn is documented as having an `Item` method for which the documentation says:

> If the specified key is not found, then a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) is returned.

What I can't *immediately* see is how you would light on the `Item` method specifically as the name of the indexer (`this[]`) method if you didn't know that that was a standard convention...

Answer (score 0):

Request.Params is a NameValueCollection, which will return 'null' if a key does not exist in the collection.

So, if the URL was:

http://localhost

Then `context.Request.Params["foo"]` would be `null`.

Now, if the request was:

http://localhost?foo=

Then `context.Request.Params["foo"]` would be `""`.

I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using Extension Methods:

```
if(!Request["Name"].IsNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    // do something with the Request["Name"] value 
                    // OR 
                    // You can extract the Request["Name"] into a variable and do the same with the variable
                }
```

The ExtentionMethod look something like this:

```
  public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string str)
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(str); 
        }
```

Thanks!